# How to change the color of raisedButton when selected

Tags: flutter

I want to do something very simple, but I think I am missing a step because it is not working. What I need to do is to change the style of the raisedButton when selected.

So far I did this:

```
Container ChoiceChip(String chipName) {
    bool isButtonPressed = false;
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: isButtonPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          chipName,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isButtonPressed = !isButtonPressed;
          });
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          side: BorderSide(
            color: isButtonPressed ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If I print something onPressed it shows in the terminal, but it is not changing the color of the button

Answer (score -1):

Define the boolean in the stateless/stateful widget before BuildContext. Then make use of initState to store the state of the boolean value on launch. Finally make sure you do a full restart of your app to re-initialize the app.